# How to upgrade to latest terraform version in GCP Cloud Shell

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

A colleague developed a terraform script that used version 0.14.x of Terraform.  He uses a local Cloud Shell while I use the Cloud Shell in the GCP console.

The GCP console reports the terraform version as being 0.12.x.

How do you update the version to the latest?  I tried following the Debian instructions from the Hashicorp web site and now, if I try to follow them again, I am told I have version 0.14.x installed but if I type terraform --version I still see 0.12.x.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch between versions of TF by typing the command **tfswitch** on your terminal.

or else what you can is to remove the old version from path

you can get the current version path from `which terraform`

you can remove the old release from the old path and add the binary to same place in GCP Cloud CLI.

You can directly download the zip into GCP cloud CLI using :

```
wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.14.7/terraform_0.14.7_linux_amd64.zip
```

**unzip** and set the **binary** at the same path

Comment: "tfswitch" does not appear to be installed in Google Cloud Shell so that option is out. What I did end up doing was to simply download the zip and extract to my home directory and then create an alias to the path in my home directory.